# Binding Entitys to a WPF form MVVM

Tags: wpf, vb.net, entity-framework, mvvm

My question might require several answers or a good example I might be going about things all wrong, I appreciate any help.

In essence I am trying to bind a WPF form to my Entity Frame work model, at the same time i am trying to learn MVVM for my WPF form, so there should be loads of examples have used lots to get where i am but I cant find one pinning it together, doesn't help i'm not proficient enough in c# to read it i have to put it though a translator all the time.

-

I think i need to create a new Class inherited from one of my Entity's, to host the extra property my view model needs

```
Public Property IsSelected As Boolean
Public Property IsReadOnly As Boolean
```

and all the others...

However, i would also like the Entity Frame Work context to track my entity's so the navigation property's on those entity's still work i can call SaveChanges... this doesn't seem to work if i have new classes.
**And that is the crux of it i cant figure out how i make EF and MVVM play nicely together.**

The only thing i can think of doing is creating a class with one of my Entity's as a Private and re-create all the property's manually but surely this is the point of inheritance.

```
Class Observation_View
Private Co_Observations_TBL as Observations_TBL

Public New (ByVal Observation as Observations_TBL)
Co_Observations_TBL = Observation 
End Sub

Public Property Observed_Value as Single
 Get
  Return Co_Observations_TBL.Observed_Value  
 End Get
 Set
  Co_Observations_TBL.Observed_Value =  value
  RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("Observed_Value"))
 End Set
End Property
```

(I might need to register the entity with the context in the constructor.)

It just feels like this cant be the way i'm supposed to do it, i have to re-implement PropertyChanged and all sorts just a mess.

Thanks
Tim

side note i'm a beginner and I cant seem to find a elegant way of constructing a child class using a parent object or a parent using a child, again i seem to have to through all the objects property's, is this really right?

Comment: At first glance, try passing your Observations_TNL entity as `ByRef`. I believe that should fix your change tracking problem.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing lacking in your MVVM is the ViewModel.

Basically what you need to is create a ViewModel which then exposes properties. These properties are objects from your Model. Then you set the DataContext of your xaml-page to an instance of that ViewModel. You can load the objects you want to show from the constructor or anywhere else upon constructing it.

For example, you could have an ObservationViewModel which exposes a list of Observations and a SelectedObservation:

```
Public Class ObservationViewModel

    Public Property Observations As IEnumerable(Of Observation)
    ' implement the property and raise PropertyChangedEvent here in the setter (omitted for brevity)

    Public Property SelectedObservation as Observation
    ' implement the property and raise PropertyChangedEvent here in the setter (omitted for brevity)    
End Class
```

Then in your view you bind the Observations and the selected observation to your ViewModel:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Observations}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObservation, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

To save your changes to your database, use a Command. You declare a command in your ViewModel (the class shown above) like this:

```
 ' Note: to use RelayCommand you should add an MVVM-framework such as MVVM Light
 Public Property SaveCommand as New RelayCommand(
     Sub()
         ' Save the list of objects that have changed here
     End Sub()
 )
```

After that you can bind a save-button in the XAML like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
```

Comment: I think `Observation_View` is his viewmodel.

Comment: Hm, yeah, I guess, but in his ViewModel he's exposing all the properties again. If he just implements INotifyProperty changed in his model, that's not necesary

Comment: I think i’m agreeing with you, I am trying to create a View Model. In that view model i want a collection of Observation  objects to give my view something to bind to, which is what i think you are telling me. However, the Observation_TBL object from my entity frame work model won’t do the job it needs more properties tailored to the view objects such as the IsSelected property that obviously i don’t want in the Entity frame work. 
So the bit i am struggling with is designing that Observation Object such that the entity frame work will track it and it has the additional propertys. 
Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you're trying to bind only the Model through the ViewModel to View's DataContext. So that's why you're trying to add view management properties in the Model and this is wrong.
a Model is only a part of stuff can be bound to a View via a ViewModel. What you need to do is to bind the ViewModel object it self to the View's DataContext.
Entity framework is kind of a data layer between your app and the database. You may need to master MVVM first than go for Entity Framework

Comment: TBH I’m far better at EF than WPF all my UI’s until now have been crude things written like it was a Win Forms app. I could create a View model thing out of my entity’s, by adding the properties in partial classes for my entities(I’m not using code first).   But I’m sure that’s also not how it was intended.

Answer (score 0):

I've found putting your EF collections into an ObservableCollection is the simplest way to go about it, and implement INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyCollectionChanged for your WPF bindings.

```
Dim _dbcontext as New EntityFrameworkEntities
Dim _PrivateCollection as ObservableCollection(Of T)

Public Property Collection as ObservableCollection(Of T)
  Get 
    Return _PrivateCollection
  End Get
  Set(value as ObservableCollection(Of T))
    [Insert Validation Here]
    _PrivateCollection = Value
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Collection"))
  End Set
End Property
```

Then be sure to fill your collection in your constructor, as well as add your handlers to add or delete objects from your entity Framework.

```
Public Sub New()
  _PrivateCollection = New ObservableCollection(Of T)(dbcontext.EFCollectionName.ToList)
  AddHandler Collection.CollectionChanged, AddressOf OnEFCollectionChanged
End Sub

Public Event CollectionChanged(Sender as Object, e As NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged

Private Sub OnEFCollectionChanged(Sender as Object, e as NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
  If e.Action = NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add Then
    For Each Item In e.NewItems
      dbcontext.EFCollectionName.Add(Item)
    Next
  End If
  If e.Action = NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove Then
    For Each Item In e.OldItems
      dbcontext.EFCollectionName.Remove(Item)
    Next
  End If
End Sub
```

Obviously change the Private Collection and Collection names to whatever you want them to be called.  Then change the EFCollectionName to whatever the entities are called in your Entity Framework.

Now just add the SaveChanges command in your ViewModel and call it from a save button, or however you want to wire it up.